# .htaccess RewriteEngine each URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the `.htaccess` send each file/directory to my `index.php`. I have this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?urlparam=$1 [NC,L]
```

But this error apears on `mysite.com/foobar`, if directory exists:

> Forbidden
>
> You do not have permission to access this document.

If not:

> Not Found
>
> The requested document was not found on this server. (404)

Comment: It is unclear (to me) if you would like urls for files or directories, even if they exist, to be routed through index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having both the `!-f` and `-f` set of conditions makes no sense. This is essentially saying:

> Perform this rewrite rule if the request does not match an existing file and the request also matches an existing file.

Obviously, you can't have both.

What you want is simply:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?urlparam=$1 [NC,L]
```